# Using bash variable in awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a situation where I need to use the bash variable in awk, but it is not working.

file.txt

```
Fruit Good
```

try.sh

```
var="apple"
awk '{print $var " " $1 " " $2}' file.txt
```

Expected Output:

```
apple Fruit Good
```

Code Output:

```
Fruit Good Fruit Good
```

It seems the content of `file.txt` is get replaced by variable `$var`. Please suggest me correct approach.

Comment: `awk -v var="$var" '{print var, $1, $2}' file.txt`

Comment: See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24

Comment: @EdMorton, Thanks for sharing the link, it is having good examples.